# Span inside of Anchor

Tags: syntax

So, this is a really silly question but I am not familiar with the following format and just trying to learn it.

I am trying to put `<span>` something `</span>` inside of `<a>` but I am not making it work.

```
$output.= '<a class="royal_title_href" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . the_title('', '', false) . '<span>' '</span>' '</a>';
```

Could someone help me the format?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work...

```
$output.= '<a class=\"royal_title_href\" href=\"' . get_permalink() . '\">' . the_title('', '', false) . '<span>' '</span>'</a>';
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry it is not working either. (I missed `'` at the end of `</a>`, which is fixed now). Anyway, I am not sure if I put the `<span>` correctly.